# No such file or directory #include "opencv2/face.hpp" while compiling facerec_fisherfaces with c++ in ubuntu?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

I'm new to Opencv version 3.1.0 and trying to compile the code of facerec_fisherfaces.cpp http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/_downloads/facerec_fisherfaces.cpp

using this compile.sh file

```
LIBS="-lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib"
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -fpic -Wall -c "untitled.cpp" $LIBS

g++ -shared -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -o libuntitled.so untitled.o -L/usr/local/lib $LIBS

g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -o untitled untitled.o -L/usr/local/lib $LIBS

exit 0
```

the error in the terminal is :

No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/face.hpp"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper answer to my question :)

you need to download so extra modules from :

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib